# Is it possible to get autocompletion and intellisense for JsTestDriver in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, autocomplete, js-test-driver

I'm currently using Eclipse (ENIDE - node studio edition) to run jsTestDriver tests. Is it possible to get code completion and Intellisense working for jsTestDriver features?

e.g. code completion doesn't work on assertEquals in the following sample:-

```
   GreeterTest = TestCase("GreeterTest");

   GreeterTest.prototype.testGreet = function() {
var greeter = new myapp.Greeter();
assertEquals("Hello World!", greeter.greet("World"));
```

};

also there's no completion on GreeterTest.prototype.